# Multiple files for a single SQLite database

Tags: sqlite

Afaik, SQLite stores a single database in a single file. Since this would decrease the performance when working with large databases, is it possible to explicitly tell SQLite not to store the whole DB in a single file and store different tables in different files instead?

Comment: Why you need it? what is the functionality which can not be achieved/Or issues that can occur by using the single DB file?

Comment: I'm planning to replace an Oracle DB with SQLite. Thousands of transactions will throughout the day and I'm afraid that reading and writing a single file will slow down the process.
Anyway it seems that SQLite won't be the best option to handle such a large database.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't need a join between these tables you can manually split the DB and say which tables are in which DB (=file).

I don't think that it's possible to let SQLite split your DB in multiple files, because you connect to a DB by telling the filename.

Comment: Can't afford to have tables as different DBs. Also the number of maximum attached databases is limited to 62 in SQLite. :(

Answer (score 45):

I found out, that it *is* possible.

Use:

sqlite3.exe MainDB.db

`ATTACH DATABASE 'SomeTableFile.db' AS stf;`

Access the table from the other database file:

`SELECT * FROM stf.SomeTable;`

You can even join over several files:

```
SELECT *
FROM MainTable mt
JOIN stf.SomeTable st
ON (mt.id = st.mt_id);
```

https://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html

tameera said there is a limit of 62 attached databases but I never hit that limit so I can't confirm that.

The big advantage besides some special cases is that you limit the fragmentation in the database files and you can use the `VACUUM` command separately on each table!

Comment: Apparently there is a limit switch to limit the number of databases that can be attached to a connection `SQLITE_LIMIT_ATTACHED`. Maybe tameera hit that limit in the test?

Answer (score 4):

SQLite database files can grow quite large without any performance penalties.

The things that might degrade performance are:

- file-locking contention
- table size (if using indexes and issuing write queries)

Also, by default, SQLite limits the [number of attached databases to 10](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16897503/89771).

Anyway, [try partition your tables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17110004/89771). You'll see that SQLite can grow enormously this way.

Comment: As far as I understand from the linked post, the partitioning concept is self-implemented. SQLite has no build-in partitioning support like some other  RDBMSs. Correct?