# Storing a list of sqlite databases

Tags: android, sqlite

I am looking to create a list of SQLite databases within an android application. All of the databases in the list share the same schema.

Is it possible to store an ArrayList of SQLite databases in another SQLite database? If not, what data structure would you recommend to store the list of databases in SQLite?

Comment: @cricket_007 ... **what**?! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_schema

Comment: @Rotwang - what about it? "In a relational database, the schema defines the tables, fields, relationships, views... "

Comment: @cricket_007 Which means that databases **do have a schema**, as opposed of what you are saying... `Tables have schema. Databases don't` - **simply ridiculous**.

Comment: There is no reason to do that. This sounds like a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 0):

You can save a list of whatever you want in a database.

I think you're conflating two concepts though - an ArrayList is a *Java* class, *not* a database concept. It doesn't make sense to talk about which data structure you're using to store something in the database - a data structure is something like a Linked List, Hash Table, Binary Tree, etc., which has nothing to do with databases. The only way to store something in a database is in tables.

Answer (score 0):

> I am looking to create a list of SQLite databases within an android application

Sure.

```
ArrayList<SQLiteDatabase> databases;
```

Though, seems entirely unnecessary...

> All of the databases in the list share the same schema

Not quite sure I understand that point... All the tables in all the databases have the same schema? There is only one table in each of the databases? If they are all the same, why not merge into one database file?

Additional note: [Mulitple files for a single Sqlite database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9410011/multiple-files-for-a-single-sqlite-database)

> Is it possible to store an ArrayList of SQLite databases in another SQLite database?

Not that I am aware of. See [**SQLite Data Types**](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).
That would also be a lot of storage space required to do that, if possible.

You use one database with many tables and `FOREIGN KEY` reference values to create data mapping and the idea of "nesting" in RDBMS.

> If not, what data structure would you recommend to store the list of databases in SQLite?

You can store a list of `File` objects with the location of the database files on disk, then loop over those and use

[**`SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(File file, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory)`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#openOrCreateDatabase(java.io.File,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory))