# attach multiple database in sqlite

Tags: c#, sqlite

i have a project that i have to use SQLite as database
in this project we have tons of data maybe more than 1 terabyte and i want to if the database file was more than 500gig add another database file and use it for inserting data but show me both data from all databases that maybe one or 10 database most show me all of data from all databases.
i found this article:
https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-attach-database/
can i doing like this?
if answer is yes, how can i do it?

Comment: SQLite is designed for single user, single file scenarios. It's the same as a local file would be, it gives you only the structured access to it. I guess it will be very slow on such a big database.
You should rather try to identify your biggest table, maybe it has file attachments or similiar ? And store it yourself in a binary format, or in the file system.
So you keep your core database smaller. SQLite is not the right choice for a Terabyte. Take another free database like MySQL, oder SQL-Express.

Comment: Already answered. Please check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9410011/multiple-files-for-a-single-sqlite-database

Comment: _"If your data will grow to a size that you are uncomfortable or unable to fit into a single disk file, then you should select a solution other than SQLite."_ from https://sqlite.org/whentouse.html

Comment: dear @JQSOFT tnx for your responding but that is a different question i have one big table
dear Holger i just have one table and it will growing up very fast
unfortunately i cant install MSSQL or MySQL that want admin permission

Comment: @Holger  Sqlite engine can attach multiple database files and even join data between them.

Comment: @C Perkins, yes, for transfer/import/export scenarios. But the idea why SQLite was 'invented' is to have it all in one Blob. "possible" and "designed for" are different things.