# Is there a way to store efficiently chunks of dictionary objects in Python?

Tags: python, performance, dictionary, serialization

I am using Python and the `pickle` module. I need to store several big dictionaries with similar structures in separate files, and then create a lookup that loops through the keys one by one and processes the data contained in all dictionaries for that key.

Basically, I will have one dictionary for each day with the structure:

```
daily_dict = {
    'a': <complex structure of data>,
    'a1': <complex structure of data>,
    ...
    'key_K': <complex structure of data>,
    ...
}
```

The complex structure of data is another dictionary, that contains several fields (containing lists) that I should process afterward. There is no way of reducing the size of these fields before the outer processing, as I have to aggregate data from several days before extracting the features that I need.

And I want to create the dictionary:

```
merged_dict = {
    'a': processing of all 'a' keys in all daily dictionaries,
    ...
}
```

So basically I will need to loop in the keys and merge the dictionaries by key, then process them accordingly. The thing is that with the pickle module I have to load all the files before getting to read the keys.

- I can only process the data for each day and then loop in the keys after storing the intermediate results, as I am parsing daily data each time and I cannot keep everything in memory.
- Each dictionary takes up to 2 GB when pickled, so it takes a long time to load them again for the other loop, and as I said I cannot have them all in memory at once.
- Finally, as you can guess, I have size constraints as I have to process a lot of data, so I cannot change to a format that takes up too much space. I can use a trade-off if the data becomes faster to read, but I'd rather avoid that.

I wonder if there is some smarter way of storing them, given the fact that I don't need to read all the data at once, but rather I would read only part of the file (single key or a bunch of keys) at a time.

My idea is to create separate files with keys sorted alphabetically, so I can read chunks of each dictionary instead of loading the whole, and I won't need a lookup table (e.g., I can read all keys beginning with the letter 'a' easily). I think in this way it is feasible, but I wonder if there is a more efficient way, as the files will be highly unbalanced in this way.

I apologize, I cannot share the content of the dictionaries, but only the structure.

Comment: Storing large amounts of data in pickles is inherently slow, so it's not worth looking for a more efficient solution using that approach. Use a relational database (e.g. sqlite), which is designed for precisely this kind of task. The initial overhead of changing approaches will be hugely offset by the later gains.

Comment: I'm just thinking from my head: For the data I would rather use SQLite database. You can have multiple sqlite database files and use ATTACH and DETACH mechanism to load/store from them, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9410011/multiple-files-for-a-single-sqlite-database

Comment: My problem is that the data I am storing might be hard to translate to a table. Each dictionary contains also lists, and these lists also have different lengths. Is there a way to handle this kind of data as well, in SQLite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pickle load and dump is an atomic operation so you must handle tons of data to retrieve only value of a single key.
I suggest to introduce a db k/value like [redis](https://redis.io/) that can handle easily that mass of data. python drives is easy to use and this solution let you to have all data available.
In fact this facility [redis-dict](https://github.com/Attumm/redis-dict) let you to use redis like a dict transparently so this have a small impact on existing code.

Comment: I believe Redis would keep everything in RAM, is that correct? Or there is a way of storing redis databases in disk, and then load them again on memory when needed?

Comment: Redis is born to handle these kind of problem, and it's no limited to ram size. It can handle efficienlty ton of data. Do not worry for this, lot of questions are [here](https://redis.io/topics/faq)

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try!